# how to track moving sphere path?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm working on a project in C++ and OpenGL on Visual Studio 2010 and I have some spheres moving around the screen. How can I track their movement and draw a line behind them while they move?

Answer (score 2):

Store their positions in a vector over time and each frame you draw the points from the vector with GL_LINE_STRIP.

Checkout some OpenGL tutorial if you don't know how to draw the lines themselves.